# Why can't i use my class in Nightmare.evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I am trying to scrape a website for data about anime using Nightmare and am using the `evaluate` function to run `querySelectorAll` in the document. I would like to create and return an array of `Anime`(very simple class only having two properties) in the `evaluate` function.

Here's my code:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')

const URL = 'https://horriblesubs.info/shows/'

const browser = Nightmare({
    show: true
})

class Anime {
    constructor(name, url) {
        this.name = name
        this.url = url
    }
}

browser
    .goto(URL)
    .evaluate(() => {
        let shows = document.querySelectorAll('.ind-show')
        var array = new Array()
        shows.forEach((e, i) => {
            array.push(
                new Anime(e.textContent, e.firstChild.href)
            )
        })
        return array
    })
    .then(shows => {
        console.log(shows)
    })
```

Unfortunately, NodeJS tells me that the class Anime is not defined. How can I fix it or get the same results ?

Answer (score 0):

The `evaluate` function parameter is executed in the browser context, not the test.

You'd return a simple array and create the `Anime` instances in your `then` function.

See the [Nightmare `evaluate` docs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2) and [this Nightmare issue discussion](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/1356) for more info.